# In the console: what does the question mark in a square mean, and how do I detect it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding

In the console, for some unprocessable characters it emits this:

[image]

Can someone tell me:

1) What exactly does that symbol mean?

2) What's it called?

3) How can I detect which chars will give me that - e.g. if I want to write code to find all the integers for which the string representation is rendered as that, how do I do it:

```
(60000..70000).select {|i| what_do_i_do_here?(i) }
```

Comment: I think it would depend on the font? Some fonts might have a character for particular codepoints which others don't. So I don't know if there's a way to tell in general. Even given a particular font I suspect it would be hard to tell how things are rendered programmatically.

Comment: Just a joke: send it to yourself on WhatsApp and you'll get the result on your phone :-p

Comment: This symbol looks like a space in Google slides but if you copy paste into a notepad it looks like a question mark in a square. Attempts to remove unprintable characters are not removing it.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol means that the font cannot display a character.

The name: check out the sister site: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62524/what-do-you-call-the-phenomenon-where-a-rectangle-is-shown-because-a-font-lack , so officially in Unicode: *replacement glyph*, but often it is called *tofu*.

It depends on your font, and the font/language setting. Note: you are just trying single code-points, but some glyphs ("letters" as displayed by a font), could be made by several combining code-points (the "char" in many computer languages).

I really do not know how to know which characters are supported by a specific font (just by having the font). Often the font creators tell you which glyphs are implemented.